# WARN in git commit

Tags: git, github

Does anyone know how to explain these warnings?
I have already done the entire communication configuration and ssh key.

```sh
~/MIT/arlindomcorrea.github.io (main)
$ git commit -m 'try 4'

**[WARN]** Non-allowed remote URL in the repo: git@github.com:arlindomcorrea/arlindomcorrea.github.io.git

**[WARN]** File index.html is encoded in an unsupported format and was not checked!

[main 322db0b] try 4
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

The `git push` went OK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Git command for adding a notice/warning before pushing to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290477/is-there-a-git-command-for-adding-a-notice-warning-before-pushing-to-master)

Comment: Neither warning appear in the git source code, so to @NeutralMe's point that is probably something you or the repo has configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first your [hook folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073454/6309), for any active hook (possibly [client-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), like a pre-commit one)

Typically, a `git commit -n -m 'try 4'` would [bypass a pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309), *not* displaying those messages.
If you can check that, that would confirm an active pre-commit script.

Answer (score 0):

VonC;

Really It's Works!
Do this is characteristics that I can change or I just ignore?

Evidence:

```
arlindo.correa@CPX-VW4XYJ2UWTK MINGW64 ~/MIT/arlindomcorrea.github.io (main)
$ vim index.html

arlindo.correa@CPX-VW4XYJ2UWTK MINGW64 ~/MIT/arlindomcorrea.github.io (main)
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
 (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   index.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

arlindo.correa@CPX-VW4XYJ2UWTK MINGW64 ~/MIT/arlindomcorrea.github.io (main)
$ git add .

arlindo.correa@CPX-VW4XYJ2UWTK MINGW64 ~/MIT/arlindomcorrea.github.io (main)
$ git commit -n -m 'try 5'
[main f8f4169] try 5
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

arlindo.correa@CPX-VW4XYJ2UWTK MINGW64 ~/MIT/arlindomcorrea.github.io (main)
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 286 bytes | 143.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To github.com:arlindomcorrea/arlindomcorrea.github.io.git
   322db0b..f8f4169  main -> main``
```